# Creating a private network for internal VMs

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, routing, xen

I am trying to configure a private network for use with my Xen VMs, in addition to the public network in use by another of the VMs (VM1, which has its own public IP).

So far, I have the public side working perfectly with a bridged network...

On the host machine:

```
eth0: 91.x.x.1, gateway: 91.x.x.254
xenbr0: bridged with eth0
VM1 connected to xenbr0, with a new IP address, 91.x.x.2, and gateway 91.x.x.254
```

On the host machine, I've also created a private dummy ethernet port:

```
dummy0: 192.168.1.1
```

and a bridge via XenServer, pdummy0 (using these instructions http://tipstricks.itmatrix.eu/?p=681)

Everything's working there, as well - the two VMs connected to the bridge can ping each other, as well as the host machine via the private 192.168.1.1 IP.

```
VM2: 192.168.1.2
VM3: 192.168.1.3
```

The last step here, is to have each of those VMs (VM2 & VM3) to be able to see the internet... What routes / IP forwarding do I need to set up to make that happen?

Sample route from VM2, /sbin/route:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enable packet forwarding on your host.

```
# /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

then add forwarding rules on your host iptables rules

```
# iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 91.x.x.1/24 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A FORWARD -s 91.x.x.1/24 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

add static routes in your router via console or webui.

```
#ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 91.x.x.1
```